# remove extension from image filename php

Tags: php

I am loading a folder of images into a html page using the following php code.

The problem I am having is that the file name which is being brought through in order to be used as the image caption is showing the file extension.

The part of the code where the name is being pulled is the title='$img'

How do I get it to remove the file extension?

```
<?php
$string =array();
$filePath='images/schools/';  
$dir = opendir($filePath);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) { 
    if (eregi("\.png",$file) || eregi("\.jpeg",$file) || eregi("\.gif",$file) || eregi("\.jpg",$file) ) { 
        $string[] = $file;
    }
}
while (sizeof($string) != 0) {
    $img = array_pop($string);
    echo "<img src='$filePath$img' title='$img' />";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a "state-of-the-art" OO code, I suggest the following:

```
$files = array();
foreach (new FilesystemIterator('images/schools/') as $file) {
    switch (strtolower($file->getExtension())) {
        case 'gif':
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'png':
            $files[] = $file;
            break;
    }
}

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo '<img src="' . htmlentities($file->getPathname()) . '" ' .
         'title="' . htmlentities($file->getBasename('.' . $file->getExtension())) . '" />';
}
```

Benefits:

- You do not use the deprecated `ereg()` functions anymore.
- You escape possible special HTML characters using `htmlentities()`.

Comment: Looks like pretty old-school OO code nowadays. It is also worth pointing out that the `getBasename(…)` is the relevant part for the original question.

Comment: @salathe: What's "hip" nowadays then? I mean, extending `FilesystemIterator` with an own class implementing an `getImageFiles()` method will contain the same stuff.

Comment: Hi, thanks for everyones suggestions. I've gone with Shi's suggestion. Seems to do the job pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the filename without the extension using [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/pathinfo) so for title='' you could use `pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_without_ext = substr($file, 0, strrpos(".", $file));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get rid of file extention with substr, like this:

```
$fileName =  $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
$file_without_ext = substr($fileName, 0, strrpos($fileName,"."));
```